# Javascript - Scroll container with transcript while the audio player

Tags: javascript, audio, ember.js, smooth-scrolling

I have an audio player that plays an mp3 file and a container underneath that displays a transcript of the text. The audio file is split into 2 channels so there's one speaker on the left of the transcript and one on the right.

As the audio is playing, I'd like to be able to gradually scroll the container in sync with the audio so that the portion that is playing on the audio file is at the top of the transcript container at the time. I'd also like to be able to pause the scrolling as I pause the audio player, or jump to the portion of the transcript as I use the scrubber of the audio player.

In other words, I want the transcript container to stay in sync with the audio without having to manually scroll the container. I'm not sure the best way to go about doing this, but I know I'd like to avoid jQuery if possible.

**Updated**
Here's an image of what the base looks like. I can't really show what I'm trying to achieve but I'm hoping with the picture and the description it will make a bit more sense. As you scrub with the circular handle, it should scroll the transcript to that portion of the call.

[image: Transcript and Audio]

Thanks,
Brennan

Comment: Can you give a UI screen with the results you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @BenilMathew thanks for the suggestion. Just updated.

Comment: what kind of audio-player plugin are you using? Or is it self-made? From the plain [html5 Audio](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) the `timeupdate` event looks like to one to hook into.

Comment: Utilizing wavesurfer.js so I have access to plenty of hooks. I'm just unsure the best way to go about it. Even if someone could offer some psuedo code or walk me through the best approach I could probably figure out the path.

Comment: I'm afraid you'd have to post more relevant code for us to be able to answer. Right now it would be a shot into the dark...

Comment: the audioprocess event seems to be the event to hook into.